# Windows 10 - Can't view what's causing high memory usage

Tags: windows-10, memory, performance

My PC is generally sitting towards 90% memory usage and often hitting 100%. If I look in the Task Manager I can see one app using roughly 20% but there rest of the processes don't add up to 90%.

I have 16GB of RAM.

**Processes**

[image: Processes]

**Performance**

Performance shows I'm using 13.1/15.2GB

[image: Performance]

**Users**

Users shows I'm using 86% of memory with only 5.5GB usage.

[image: Users]

Clearly the memory is in use but I don't know what it is or how to view it.

What is causing this?

**RamMap**

[image: Use Counts]

[image: Processes]

Comment: Please make screenshots of RAMMap and add them to the question https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap

Comment: @Gantendo I've added the Use Counts and Processes tabs. Did you want any other screenshots of it? I'm wondering if Docker could be causing this however I'd still expect to see the processes?

Comment: @Michael - Spin down your Docker instances.  Even better boot into Safe Mode and/or a minimal boot configuration. Docker is using at least 2.3 GB[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1705499/abnormally-high-ram-usage-win-10#comment2627233_1705499)

Comment: I'll give that a try. Shouldn't docker be showing somewhere in the processes? Why is it hidden?

Comment: Docker typically would be a service.  I would also look at disabling WSL2